# MySQL ordering table base on date and another numerical column

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

Assume that I have a table like this:

```
+----+--------------+-----+-----------+
| ID |Date          | DD  |    City   | 
+----+--------------+-----+-----------+
|  2 | 2016-05-14   | 102 | NY        |
|  5 | 2016-05-12   | 101 | London    | 
|  3 | 2016-05-13   | 101 | Tokyo     |
|  6 | 2016-05-12   | 102 | LA        |
|  4 | 2016-05-14   | 101 | KC        |
|  7 | 2016-05-13   | 102 | Delhi     |
+----+--------------+-----+-----------+
```

How Can I get Sorted result by using MySQL and SQL statements base on Date and DD columns that it be like this:

```
+----+--------------+-----+-----------+
| ID |Date          | DD  |    City   | 
+----+--------------+-----+-----------+
|  2 | 2016-05-12   | 101 | NY        |
|  5 | 2016-05-12   | 102 | London    | 
|  3 | 2016-05-13   | 101 | Tokyo     |
|  6 | 2016-05-13   | 102 | LA        |
|  4 | 2016-05-14   | 101 | KC        |
|  7 | 2016-05-14   | 102 | Delhi     |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+---+
```

it means sort table by Date column but each day also sorted by DD.

when I use ORDER BY Date,DD the out put is like this

```
    +----+--------------+-----+-----------+
| ID |Date          | DD  |    City   | 
+----+--------------+-----+-----------+
|  2 | 2016-05-12   | 101 | NY        |
|  5 | 2016-05-13   | 101 | London    | 
|  3 | 2016-05-14   | 101 | Tokyo     |
|  6 | 2016-05-12   | 102 | LA        |
|  4 | 2016-05-13   | 102 | KC        |
|  7 | 2016-05-14   | 102 | Delhi     |
+----+----------+-----+-----------+---+
```

this is not true for me.

Comment: just end with... `order by Date, DD`

Comment: You can also have different orders per column, e.g. `order by Date asc, DD desc;` just to inform you as good to know thing. ;)

Comment: @MrSimpleMind, I know the usage of order but when I use it the relust is like this: 2016-05-12 101 .... 2016-05-13 101 ... 2016-05-14 101 ... 2016-05-12 102 ... 2016-05-13-102 ... 2016-05-14-102

Comment: Can you show your table create stmnt

Comment: Very strange output, I mean, even if your Date is char(10) it will order as per request... so something else is going wrong here. Show please your create table statement.

Comment: Something is wrong with your output, looks like you modified it? London (id 5) has dd 101 and KC (id 4) has dd 102. While in other output they have 101 and 101, and also 101 and 102. ???

Comment: take it is bro @MrSimpleMind the city column is not important in example

Comment: Okey your query is not just a simple table, that explains all. Well .. I would suggest that you edit your question.. Some people like to come with funny questions, thought this one was something like that. As modified dd numbers. As order by is the solution ... but your quey is not just a table query. It is hard to read a mixed query. So please update your question. (Even if city is not important, so the id and dd mismatches! nothing to do with city!).

Comment: The assuming a table is one thing and assuming a query output from previous query is another thing. ;) please understand I (and others here) want to help... nothing more!

Comment: @MrSimpleMind yes I know bro, but the answer of this example can solve my problem in my complicated sql statement. anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `Date`,`DD`
```

Answer (score -1):

SELECT * FROM `table` ORDER BY `Date` ASC,`DD` DESC